# JMeter Load testing - HttpHostConnectException: Connection refused: connect on windows server 2012

Tags: windows, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, windows-server-2012

I am doing Load Testing for my application using JMeter. Load Test is running successfully for 1000 threads without any error on MacBook and Windows 10 systems.

However when I am running on Windows Server 2012, It is running fine 100 threads but when I am increasing threads to 250 or 500, I am getting the following error:

```
  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8050 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:404)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:935)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:646)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)&#xd;
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)&#xd;
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)&#xd;
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect&#xd;
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)&#xd;
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:493)&#xd;
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:482)&#xd;
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)&#xd;
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:339)&#xd;
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:603)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)&#xd;
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)&#xd;
    ... 19 more&#xd;
```

I am using Apache Jmeter - 5.4.1.

I have spent an entire day searching for a solution without success. There were many similar issues but none helping my case.

I think some configuration changes are required but don't exactly what.

**UPDATE 1**

I have updated TCP/IP Registery parameters as well to (but no success):

`TcpTimedWaitDelay`: REG_DWORD=0x0000001e(30)
`MaxUserPort`:REG_DWORD=0x0000fffe(65534)
`TcpNumConnections`:REG_DWORD=0x00fffffe(1677214)

**UPDATE 2**

It seems the problem is not with the OS version, but with that specific machine. I installed windows server 2012 on my laptop in a virtual Box and tested it. I sent a request with 500 threads without any error.

Host system spec: 8 GB RAM, 4 CPU, Windows 10
Guest system spec: 4 GB RAM, 2 CPU, windows server 12

**UPDATE 3**

Screenshot of configurations:

[image]

Can anyone help, please?
Thank you.

Comment: `Connection refused` points to server. It possibly means server is unable to process the requests.  Did you try `perfmon` to monitor server parameters when you get `connection refused` error? we can eliminate server side issue with this.

Comment: Yes. Continuously checked server side but no error was thrown there.

Comment: Do you have other components as firewall, cloudflare, other application that limit?

Comment: JMeter and My Application is running on the same system and I am using localhost instead of IP for making calls. I don't think firewall will come into play

Comment: I created a VM in hyper-V on the same host machine and installed windows server 2012. Installed a separate instance of the same application and tested, It was running fine up to 1000 threads without any error.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/648424/windows-server-2012-r2-runs-out-of-ephemeral-ports-though-it-shouldnt) question, but you can tune using the following solutions:

1. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`

> TcpMaxDataRetransmissions - Timeout limit of TCP unacknowledged data segments retransmission on actual connection = 5.

2. Updating ephemeral TCP port range

> To change the port range, use this command:

> ```
> netsh int <ipv4|ipv6> set dynamic <tcp|udp> start=number num=range
> ```

3. Adding shutdown command

> because a reboot is required for the TCP stack changes.

> Increase Pool Size for Ephemeral TCP Ports

> ```
>  Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name MaxUserPort -Value 65534 -Force | Out-Null
>  Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name TcpTimedWaitDelay -Value 30 -Force | Out-Null
>  Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name TcpNumConnections -Value 16777214 -Force | Out-Null
>  Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters' | New-ItemProperty -Name TcpMaxDataRetransmissions -Value 5 -Force | Out-Null
>  shutdown -r -t 0
> ```

Comment: I tried above solutions still no success. I can share your these configuration if you would like to see.

Comment: I have shared a screenshot of the configurations. I have also restarted the system.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem between Jmeter and OS, Something like firewall, loadbalancer(if there is), any rule in between which restrict number of requests to the OS because of security.

Check if there is any ddos protection tools on that machine.

Try disabling firewall and test again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Jmeter and Server are on the same system and I am using localhost for making calls. So, no firewall is involved.

Answer (score 1):

My question is, should you run the load testing and the application at the same server? Resource contention is expected here. E.g. for each request, one or more thread in application needs to be spawned to handle the request.

Comment: Resource is not limiting factor. Spec of server is 32 GB RAM and  6 core

Comment: how about other resource type, networking for example? depending on what your app is doing, it could fight for connections. Have you monitored those metrics?

Answer (score 0):

The network agents like fw, lb, waf etc. should not interfere with the loopback connections. But if you have an anti-virus installed, it may slow down the server and cause the client to fail to connect within the connection timeout period.

You can test it with either increasing the client connect timeout or just disabling the av.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but when I turned on Use KeepAilve, it didn't show up anymore.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35537759)